# How is memory management in PHP different from that in Python?

Tags: php, python, memory-management, garbage-collection, webserver

What is the difference in how they are handled?

Specifically, why is it common to find Python used in production-level long lived applications like web-servers while PHP isn't given their similar efficiency levels?

Comment: Some insights http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996437/memory-management-and-python-how-much-do-you-need-to-know

Comment: PHP had rather miserable memory management before the 5.2/5.3 series. The garbage collector could not break circular references, so memory leaks were common and hard to track. This made PHP unsuitable for long-running scripts.

Comment: thanks! would you say  this is "fixed" in the 5.2/5.3 series?

Comment: Well, the garbage collection mechanism is much improved. Whether it counts as "fixed" is another matter. GC is an expensive operation to begin with, and having to handle circular references now has made it even slower. Of course, if your script never needs to have a GC run done, you'd likely never notice a difference.

Comment: Thanks again...I guess its probably at a stage where benchmarking would now be a reasonable option for figuring out how well it compares with Python for similar long-lived tasks.

Comment: I remember the documentation for PHP 2.0 boasted that it never freed any memory, instead allocating a chunk and then dumping it all at some point.  Probably, uh, not that bad any more, but that's quite a legacy to recover from.

Comment: @algorithm Why bother? Just switch to Python. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP was designed as a hypertext scripting language. Every process was designed to end after a very short time. So memory management and GC basically didn't matter.

However the ease and popularity of PHP have invoked its usage in long lived programs such as daemons, extensive calculations, socket servers etc.

PHP 5.3 introduced a lot of features and fixes that made it suitable for such applications, however in my opinion memory management was of lower significance on that matter.

PHPs error management is quite good now, but as in every programming language that I know of you can produce memory leaks.

You still cannot code in the same style that you can code Java or Python applications. A lot of PHP programs will probably show severe problems where Java/Python do not.

You can characterize this as "worse", but I would not. PHP just is a different set of tools that you have to handle different.

The company I work at has a lot of system programs and daemons written in PHP that run like a charm.

I think the biggest caveat for PHP when it comes to as you describe "production-level long lived applications" is its multi-processing and threading ability (the 2nd is basically nonexistent).

Of course there is the possibility to fork processes, access shared memory, do inter process communications and have message queues and stuff. But Python is far ahead on that matter, because it was designed bottom up for jobs like that.

Comment: +1 for the "not better or worse" comment. More people need views like this.

Comment: The lack of threads is the biggest issue, in my opinion. I've used PHP for many persistent programs, but never when I would benefit from a proper multithreaded program. I don't really think memory or speed has much to do with any popularity discrepancies, at least since 5.3.